# Could a varying voltage (0 - 600V DC) at varying frequency and current be input to a VFD to obtain a fixed voltage of 220 V 50 Hz and varying current?

Tags: vfd

A wind turbine generator produces a single phase varying voltage (0-600 V DC) at varying frequency and current.

Could the generator output be fed to a VFD to obtain a fixed voltage of 220 V 50 Hz and varying current?

The output of the VFD is to be fed to the grid.

Comment: There's no earthly reason to use a VFD to drive the grid **illegally**, when approved grid-tie inverters with mandatory anti-islanding features are easily obtained. You cannot connect things to the grid unless they are certified to standards, and I'm sure you don't want to pay UL, TUV or other agency a fortune to approve your one-off.  Taking the variable output of a wind turbine and feeding it into such an approved grid-tie inverter is also a solved problem.   You can improvise there if you enjoy re-inventing the wheel, but the grid-tie inverter must be approved equipment.